# How many possibile combinations of five differently coloured dice are there?

Tags: probability

You have five **differently coloured** dice (Numbers 1 to 6) and roll them simultaneously. How many possible combinations are there?

Our teacher said that it is basically $6^5$, but that doesn't take the colours into account?!

We thought about $6^5 \cdot 5!$, but what if all dice show the same number?

Comment: What a clickbait title. It seems to me that your teacher actually knows but you disagree. Have you tried listing the possibilities if there are only two dices? Three? If you flip two coins (say one red and one blue), are there $2^2 = 4$ or $2^2 \cdot 2! = 8$ possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still $6^5$. Colouring the dice doesn't add any more combinations than rolling 6 uncoloured dice and counting the (ordered) combinations.

Or just think of it like this:

Suppose, without loss of generality, the dice are coloured red, orange, yellow, green and blue. Then:

There are 6 possible results for the red die.

There are 6 possible results for the orange die.

There are 6 possible results for the yellow die.

There are 6 possible results for the green die.

There are 6 possible results for the blue die.

Each die's results is independent of the others. So just multiply together the possibilities for each die to get the answer $6^5$.

Comment: Coloring the dices and numbering them (to get an ordered combination) is exactly the same thing.

Comment: I completely agree.

Comment: No, in the non-colored case you will count twice 1,2,3,4,5 and 1,2,3,5,4.

Comment: peterh - these are considered distinct _ordered_ combinations so it's correct to count them twice.

Comment: @MattBecker82 Well, true. :-( The question asks the colored case.

Comment: Indeed. My point (and Najib's) is that it's equivalent to counting ordered combinations.

Comment: Have edited my answer to try to make it clearer.